# How to handle a game world that wraps, using cocos2d on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, algorithm, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game world that's much bigger than the view port, the main character stays in the center of the view port at all times and the background layer is moved around to give the impression of the character moving. I want to make it so that the game world wraps, meaning if the the character keeps traveling either left or right they will eventually end up back at the starting position. There will be moving entities in the game world so the biggest problem I foresee is that if you go to the far right of the map you should be able to see any of the moving entities that are within the first small section of the far left of the map.

I've thought a bit about this and any solution I've come up with seems far too complicated. Like creating two identical game worlds side by side and moving them around accordingly. I live in hope that there is an elegant solution to this. Any expertise you can share would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using cocos2d on the iPhone just in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Have you considered modeling your world on a sphere?

Comment: I'm using a 2d game engine, not sure how I would go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example might be to have an x,y offset for your camera, and a multidimensional array of sprite objects.

As the player moves, the offset value changes, e.g., xMove = -1.4 and yMove = +2.6.

Then you would iterate and change the positions of all the tiles by that amount.

Next, you would identify the sprites that are too far away from the center of the screen (0,0) and re-position them to the opposite side, so they will always be visible.

This would all be done on the same scheduled 'tick' so no graphical artifacts occur.

I'm pretty surprised no one has made a wrappable tile map yet for cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give cocos2d specific advice, but I would say the most common way to do this is to create one game world, draw (parts of it) multiple times and make sure that your logic for things like collisions and AI checks for wrap-around where appropriate.

So if your player character is close to the corner of the world, you'd draw the world four times with different offsets. This needn't actually draw every single thing in the world four times any more than you would normally need to draw the entire world when only a small part of it is on-screen.